# sendmail sending long messages without empty lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I get minified(without empty lines and format) text in email body when i cat the text from the file. But the file has well formatted text, is there a way i can preserve the format of text file when sending email without changing my code a lot especially with the arguments.

### tempfile

---

```
innobackupex-runner.sh: MySQL backup script
started: Tue Apr  7 20:00:01 PDT 2015

Check completed OK
New incremental backup
 failed:

---------- ERROR OUTPUT from  ----------

InnoDB Backup Utility v1.5.1-xtrabackup; Copyright 2003, 2009 Innobase Oy
and Percona LLC and/or its affiliates 2009-2013.  All Rights Reserved.

This software is published under
the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2, June 1991.

Get the latest version of Percona XtraBackup, documentation, and help resources:
http://www.percona.com/xb/p

150407 20:00:04  innobackupex: Connecting to MySQL server with DSN 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup' as 'dbbackup'  (using password: YES).
150407 20:00:04  innobackupex: Connected to MySQL server
150407 20:00:04  innobackupex: Executing a version check against the server...
150407 20:00:04  innobackupex: Done.
150407 20:00:04  innobackupex: Starting the backup operation

IMPORTANT: Please check that the backup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful backup run innobackupex
           prints "completed OK!".

innobackupex:  Using server version 10.0.17-MariaDB-wsrep

innobackupex: Created backup directory /backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-07_20-00-04

150407 20:00:04  innobackupex: Starting ibbackup with command: xtrabackup  --defaults-group="mysqld" --backup --suspend-at-end --target-dir=/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-07_20-00-04 --innodb_data_file_path="ibdata1:12M:autoextend" --tmpdir=/tmp --tables='.*[.].*' --extra-lsndir='/tmp' --incremental-basedir='/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-07_18-00-08'
innobackupex: Waiting for ibbackup (pid=4789) to suspend
innobackupex: Suspend file '/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-07_20-00-04/xtrabackup_suspended_2'

xtrabackup: Error: cannot open /backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-07_18-00-08/xtrabackup_checkpoints
xtrabackup: error: failed to read metadata from /backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-07_18-00-08/xtrabackup_checkpoints
innobackupex: got a fatal error with the following stacktrace: at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 2704
        main::wait_for_ibbackup_file_create('/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-07_20-00...') called at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 2724
        main::wait_for_ibbackup_suspend('/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-07_20-00...') called at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 1977
        main::backup() called at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 1601
innobackupex: Error: The xtrabackup child process has died at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 2704.
email toaddress
```

### Mail body

```
InnoDB Backup Utility v1.5.1-xtrabackup; Copyright 2003, 2009 Innobase Oy and Percona LLC and/or its affiliates 2009-2013. All Rights Reserved. This software is published under the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2, June 1991. Get the latest version of Percona XtraBackup, documentation, and help resources: http://www.percona.com/xb/p 150408 09:59:04 innobackupex: Connecting to MySQL server with DSN 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup' as 'dbbackup' (using password: YES). 150408 09:59:04 innobackupex: Connected to MySQL server 150408 09:59:04 innobackupex: Executing a version check against the server... 150408 09:59:04 innobackupex: Done. 150408 09:59:04 innobackupex: Starting the backup operation IMPORTANT: Please check that the backup run completes successfully. At the end of a successful backup run innobackupex prints "completed OK!". innobackupex: Using server version 10.0.17-MariaDB-wsrep innobackupex: Created backup directory /backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-59-04 150408 09:59:04 innobackupex: Starting ibbackup with command: xtrabackup --defaults-group="mysqld" --backup --suspend-at-end --target-dir=/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-59-04 --innodb_data_file_path="ibdata1:12M:autoextend" --tmpdir=/tmp --tables='.*[.].*' --extra-lsndir='/tmp' --incremental-basedir='/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-35-42' innobackupex: Waiting for ibbackup (pid=11728) to suspend innobackupex: Suspend file '/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-59-04/xtrabackup_suspended_2' xtrabackup: Error: cannot open /backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-35-42/xtrabackup_checkpoints xtrabackup: error: failed to read metadata from /backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-35-42/xtrabackup_checkpoints innobackupex: got a fatal error with the following stacktrace: at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 2704 main::wait_for_ibbackup_file_create('/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-59...') called at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 2724 main::wait_for_ibbackup_suspend('/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-59...') called at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 1977 main::backup() called at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 1601 innobackupex: Error: The xtrabackup child process has died at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 2704.
```

### Command

```
send_notification "${SUBJECTPREFIX} Failed" "`cat $TMPFILE`" ${TOADDR}


send_notification()
{
HDR="`date +%m%d%y`"
unset ct
ct=$#
if [ $ct -lt 3 ]
then
        echo "Please provide MSG text"
    usage $0 :Notification Requires  "[SUBJECT] [MSG] [TOADDR] ...(optional)..[RTNADDR] [CCADDR] "
        return
else
    subj=$1
    msg=$2
    toaddr=$3
    rtnaddr=$4
    ccaddr=$5
    if [ $ct == 3 ]
    then
        echo "email toaddress"
        echo $msg | mail -s $subj $toaddr
    elif [ $ct == 4 ]
    then
        echo "email toaddress with return address"
        echo $msg | mail -s $subj $toaddr -- -f $rtnaddr
    elif [ $ct == 5 ]
        then
        echo "email toaddress and cc with return address"
        # Now mail report out with a Return Address (not user thsat ran it)
        # CC addresses and an TO
        echo $msg | mail -s $subj -c $ccaddr $toaddr -- -f $rtnaddr
    else 
        echo "In valid number of arguments"
    fi
fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your script to pass the filename as the `msg` parameter, and `cat` the original file to the `mail` program (rather than `echo`), you will easily avoid the interpretation which discards the newlines.

That is, the *minimal* change you asked for would use this

```
cat $msg | mail -s $subj -c $ccaddr $toaddr -- -f $rtnaddr
```

Of course, someone will suggest that is a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), and note that you could rephrase it as

```
mail -s $subj -c $ccaddr $toaddr -- -f $rtnaddr < $msg
```

(which strays a little from *minimal* -- your choice).